# Google Analytics: How can I track my website being a referral path to other websites?

Tags: google-analytics, outbound

I have some links to other websites on my website and I would like to create reports on when they've been clicked on. I haven't been using Google Tag Manager or do not have any trackers in place. Is there a way to get still get such historical data?